# Пересборка библиотеки на Maven для проекта (NetBeans Java)

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

1. Есть сторонний проект на основе Maven, он собирается в...
   ну пусть будет библиотеку и кладется в локальный репозиторий Maven.
   Назову условно проект "*lib*"
2. Есть второй проект, так же созданный сторонними разработчиками.
   Так же проект Maven, использующий библиотеку из первого проекта.
   Пусть этот проект обзывается "*app*".

Разобраться как собирать эту связку удалось, хотя и не быстро: собрал в начале проект *lib*, что бы он попал в репозиторий Maven, только затем собрался второй - *app*.

НО!..  **Проблема**:

При изменении первого проекта, он вроде бы пересобирается и обновляется JAR в репозиторий.
Сборка второго так же вроде бы выполняется и все его изменения компилятся в JAR. Но при отладке обнаруживается, что тянется первая удачная сборка *lib*, а не последняя.
Причем не понятно совсем откуда - я уже менял директорию проекта, чистил репозиторий (там дата сборки обновляется, файлы новые закидываются). Но для *app* все равно этих изменений как будто нет.

**Вопрос**, как собрать измененный первый проект (*lib*) так что бы актуальная версия подтянулась вторым проектом (*app*) ? Или сказать что бы всегда тянул из репозитория зависимости не смотря ни на что ?

Дополнительно хочу уточнить, что в Java я программирую мало, с NetBeans и Maven до недавнего времени не работал.

**UPD:**
В *"app"* подключается *"lib"* следующим образом:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<!-- ... -->
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<!-- ... -->
<properties>
    <!-- ... -->
    <customutils.version>1.1</customutils.version>
    <!-- ... -->
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- ... -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.company.customutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>customutils</artifactId>
            <version>${customutils.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ... -->
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-deploy</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: 1) какой командой деплоите файлы в репозиторий ? 2) меняете ли версию "lib" при этом?

Comment: 1) Через интерфейс NetBeans 8.1 "Собрать" или "Очистить и собрать" - в конце сборки вижу отправку в локальный репозиторий. 2) Версию не меняю при этом. Проверил, поднятие версии *"lib"* и указание её же в зависимостях *"app"* ничего не меняет.

Comment: каким образом прописана "lib" в "app" pom.xml ? Скорее за все у вас net beans под собрать делается mvn package, который на самом деле не деплоит ничего в локальный репозиторий, более детально тут:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html